# SVG mask is clipping stroke on masked element

Tags: svg

I have a completely vertical `<path>` with a thick stroke-width applied. I would like to add a mask (i.e. `mask="url(#...)"`) to it, however when I do, (how do i put this?) the stroke is ignored when computing the visible area. Here's a code snippet:

```js
function toggleMask() {
  var path = $('path');
  if (path.attr('mask')) {
    path.removeAttr('mask');
  } else {
    path.attr('mask',"url(#test)");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><button onclick="toggleMask()">toggle mask</button></div>
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <defs>
    <mask id="test">
      <rect
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            x="0"
            y="0"
            fill="white">
      </rect>
      <circle r="20" cx="35" cy="80" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <path
        d="M30,30L30,300"
        stroke-width="40"
        stroke="black"></path>
  <path
      d="M50,30L100,300"
      stroke-width="40"
      stroke="black"></path>
</svg>
```

I expected the applied mask to look something like this:

[image: test]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is working as designed. In SVG, stroke is ignored when applying masks (and calculating bounding boxes, filter regions etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Add `maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`to your mask and it'll work as you want.

https://codepen.io/nerdmanship/pen/XazJVR

The reason is that when the `maskUnits` attribute is unspecified it defaults to the `objectBoundingBox` value, which means that the mask is applied to the area inside a target element's bounding box. The bounding box of a completely vertical or horizontal path has the width *or* height of 0. The result is that the mask is applied to a total area of 0 pixels of the target element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/maskUnits